# Difference Between #Define and Float?

Tags: ios, objective-c, floating-point, c-preprocessor

What would be the difference between say doing this?

```
#define NUMBER 10
```

and

```
float number = 10;
```

In what circumstances should I use one over the other?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
#define NUMBER 10
```

Will create a string replacement that will be executed by the preprocessor (i.e. during compilation).

```
float number = 10;
```

Will create a float in the data-segment of your binary and initialize it to 10. I.e. it will have an address and be mutable.

So writing

```
float a = NUMBER;
```

will be the same as writing

```
float a = 10;
```

whereas writing

```
float a = number;
```

will create a memory-access.

Comment: It should also be noted that putting `float a = 10;` (or whatever) within a header file will likely lead to duplicate symbol errors when linking.  Using a `#define` won't, though.

Answer (score 4):

As Philipp says, the `#define` form creates a replacement in your code at the preprocessing stage, before compilation. Because the `#define` isn't a variable like `number`, your definition is hard-baked into your executable at compile time. This is desirable if the thing you are repesenting is a truly a constant that doesn't need to calculated or read from somewhere at runtime, and which doesn't change during runtime.

`#defines` are very useful for making your code more readable. Suppose you were doing physics calculations -- rather than just plonking 0.98f into your code everywhere you need to use the gravitational acceleration constant, you can define it in just one place and it increases your code readability:

```
#define GRAV_CONSTANT 0.98f

...

float finalVelocity = beginVelocity + GRAV_CONSTANT * time;
```

**EDIT**
Surprised to come back and find my answer and see I didn't mention why you shouldn't use `#define`.

Generally, you want to avoid `#define` and use constants that are actual types, because `#define`s don't have scope, and types are beneficial to both IDEs and compilers.

See also this question and accepted answer: [What is the best way to create constants in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17228334/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-constants-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 0):

"#Define" is actually a preprocessor macro which is run before the program starts and is valid for the entire program

Float is a data type defined inside a program / block and is valid only within the program / block.

Comment: "before the program starts" means before it is compiled.