# Objective C Macro append to string

Tags: ios, objective-c

I think this is a very simple thing to do, but since I'm new to iOS development and objective C, I can't figure it out.

```
#define RESTFUL_PATH_PREFIX @"https://gogch.com/gch-restful";
#define LOGIN RESTFUL_PATH_PREFIX @"/login;
```

I want the result `"https://gogch.com/gch-restful/login"`

but I'm getting the result as `"https://gogch.com/gch-restful"`

other topics in stackoverflow mention only about adding a new string to the beginning of a string like,

```
#define DOMAIN "example.com"
#define SUBDOMAIN "test." DOMAIN
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the trailing semi-colon:

```
#define RESTFUL_PATH_PREFIX @"https://gogch.com/gch-restful";
                                                            ^
```

and then string constants can be concatenated by the compiler:

```
@"first" @"second"
```

instead of:

```
@"first"; @"second"
```

Answer (score 2):

It is much better practice to use constants instead of define macros.

```
static NSString *const YourPath = @"https://...";
```

And then you can concatenate your strings with `NSString stringWithFormat:` method.

Comment: @Droppy You can benefit type safety.

Comment: That's not true; the compiler will soon tell you if you try and concatenate a string and non-string type.

Comment: @Droppy you're right about this. This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17228508/4482445) explains why it is better.

Comment: It's not that it's "better" per-say, it's just more declarative. For what it's worth, I've worked with frameworks making use of both paradigms. Rule of thumb:  do what the framework does. If you're making a new framework, pick one paradigm and stick with it. You'll get a teeny bit more debugging features with constants ... that's all I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

*Since I made this answer to a question marked as a dupe, I'll also answer it here*

---

Sure, you can use defines OR you can use NSString constants. It's really a matter of preference ... I have however seen both a `#define` and an `NSString const * const` being used before. Defines are easier, and you're probably not going to save **that much** memory by having constants instead of individual immutable instances of `NSString` all over the place.

Some advice is to think about how you export the `NSString` constants. You'll probably want `EXTERN_PRIVATE` instead of `EXTERN`, but my sample code will allow all clients of your header to read the string constants you've declared therein.

#### What you can do:

1. Create a new .m/.c file with a header in Xcode
2. In the .m/.c file, declare and initialise your constants
3. Export the constant as necessary so other compilation units can access it

---

#### constants.h

```
#ifndef constants_h
#define constants_h

// Export the symbol to clients of the static object (library)
#define EXTERN extern __attribute__((visibility("default")))
// Export the symbol, but make it available only within the static object
#define EXTERN_PRIVATE extern __attribute__((visibility("hidden")))
// Make the class symbol available to clients
#define EXTERN_CLASS __attribute__((visibility("default")))
// Hide the class symbol from clients
#define EXTERN_CLASS_PRIVATE __attribute__((visibility("hidden")))
#define INLINE static inline

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

EXTERN NSString const * _Nonnull const devBaseUrl;

#endif /* constants_h */
```

---

#### constants.m

```
#include "constants.h"

NSString const * _Nonnull const devBaseUrl = @"http://127.0.0.1:8000/";
```

---

#### main.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "constants.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSLog(@"Constant value: %@", devBaseUrl);
        // Prints: Constant value: http://127.0.0.1:8000/
    }
    return 0;
}
```