# IOS How to define a String that should be used on the app multiple times

Tags: objective-c

I need to define some (static) strings that i'm going to use multiple times inside my app, I searched a little and I found that I can declare a class like this:

```
// Constants.h 
FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString *const MyFirstConstant;
FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString *const MySecondConstant;
//etc.


// Constants.m 
NSString *const MyFirstConstant = @"FirstConstant";
NSString *const MySecondConstant = @"SecondConstant";
```

And then by importing the `Constants.h` in my files I can use those strings, but is it the right approach to my needs?

I'm using Objective-C

Comment: Yeah, except drop the use of `FOUNDATION_EXPORT` and use `extern` instead.

Comment: That works.  Another approach is to use the same syntax, but do it in .h/.m files that logically "own" the constants rather than in a general-purpose location

Comment: This has been answered several times, this is my favourite one [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17228508/1792433)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is correct.  `FOUNDATION_EXPORT` ultimately resolves to the string `extern`.  That tells the compiler that the symbol is defined somewhere else, and leave it to the linker to deal with.  The declaration in the *.m is where the storage is actually defined, and that's only compiled and linked in once.  The linker finds that reference and fixes up all the extern references that get imported into other files to point to that one.

Comment: You're welcome.  I have found that the best SO answers include a solid explanation.  I hope to carry on that tradition so that people can learn, and not just copy+paste.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is.

I do it like this:

```
// Constants.h 
extern NSString *const kMyFirstConstant;

// Constants.m
NSString *const kMyFirstConstant = @"FirstConstant";
```